# In React, can I use "useParams" to access RESTful components of my URL?

Tags: reactjs, routes, restful-url

I'm using React 16.13.0.  Within my component, I can access query string params (e.g. /url?coop_id=23) like so

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
...
const { coop_id } = useParams();
```

However, how do I access the params in a RESTful format?  E.g. if my URL is /edit/23/home, what's the React way to get the "23"?  I have defined the route in my src/App.js file

```
          <Switch>
            ...
            <Route path="/edit/:id/home" component={Edit} />
```

if that's useful.

Comment: See https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { useParams} from "react-router";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Portfolio = () => {
 let { id } = useParams();
 return (
    <div>
        Portfolio component
        <p>Topic: {id}</p>
    </div>
        );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the id using :

```
console.log(this.props.match.params.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of `/edit/:id/home` you could have nested routes in your component for edit.

The edit component could look something like:

```
function Edit() {
  // We can use the `useParams` hook here to access
  // the dynamic pieces of the URL.
  let { id } = useParams();
  // We can further check if there are other parts available after the /:id
  // the path will contain those parts
  let { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/home`}>home</Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can show different stuff in your `Edit` component based on whether there is something after `/:id`.
Check out `useParams` and `useRouteMatch` for more details. Check out example at https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting for details on nesting.